# How to manage with an unusually hard bed?

Tags: hotels, sleeping

The bed in the hotel I am staying at has the rigidity of wood! It gave me a terrible night as I woke up every hour or so with loss circulation in my limbs. Even after spending the whole night in bed, I feel more tired than when I went to sleep!

The only trick I know is to sleep over the blanket, which I folded in two, but in a place where its 37C during the day, the blanket offers very little padding.

**What else can be done to improve sleep on a hard bed?**

Comment: Rock hard mattresses are common in SE Asia.  Locals are used to sleeping on thin straw mats on hard floors, so really firm mattresses seem normal to them.

Comment: I was going to say that since this is also a common problem while camping, you might find something on [the Outdoors site](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), but I had a look and [their most similar question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13879/how-can-i-get-comfortable-sleeping-on-my-side-backpacking/13885#13885) just has a lot of people suggesting expensive camping mat type products. Hopefully someone here will suggest something possible somewhere that *doesn't* have a soft mattress in a cupboard, when you're already there and cant buy/bring something!

Comment: Here's a pretty hilarious related question on the Productivity site of all places: [Sleeping on the desk (the most comfortable and simple method)](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/sleeping-on-the-desk-the-most-comfortable-and-simple-method). Especially the cartoon in answer #2...

Comment: Ask for more blankets?

Comment: @Tom - Yesterday I looked to add more blankets and I'm not sure this can even be called a mattress! It's hollow (no filling, no springs, foam, etc) and has no bottom. Just a frame and top. Only the top is so rigid that it does not bend even with 90kg on top of it!With 4 blankets over at least I did not lose circulation but I still woke up aching.

Comment: After many nights over many years sleeping on cement floors and rock hard mattresses I have neither gotten used to it or found a good solution, I just get by on top of several folded blankets.  My wife and daughter on the other hand can sack out for the night directly on the cement floor.  We all have our different comfort levels.

Comment: Make sure your sleeping on your back and not your side (Or worse, your belly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy answers here. I'd complain to the hotel if the bed was really that hard. And if you are finding this a regular problem, then maybe bringing along an extra soft layer might be an idea. The small inflatable camping mats pack down pretty small.

Comment: Indeed. It was unusually hard but they offered 4 blankets the next night and then added a foam over it on the second. Great service in Vietnam! My hotels before and after had firm beds but none of them was that hard. The inflatable mat seems like a fantastic plan-ahead idea.

Answer (score 8):

Complain to the hotel as soon as possible - it may be a fixable problem.

Some hotels have especially firm mattresses available on request. I once got one of them by accident. I complained, and the next night my bed was much more comfortable.

Comment: Yes, I did. Apparently, I got the *soft* one! Now I have a pile of blankets under the sheets, so we'll see how it turns out.

Answer (score -1):

@daamsie already mentioned the inflatable camping mats, another option is a summer sleeping bag. They can be compressed to a very small size (especially the ones with down feather), their weight is below 1 kg.

Comment: Something that can be highly compressed isn't likely to offer much padding.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @ceejayoz. I think most people use an air mattress under a sleeping bag.